# Absolute value f interval?

Tags: calculus

How would I find where the interval in which f increases and decreases in the following function.

$$f(x)=\mid 4-x^2\mid$$

What would I do find the zero

I know

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{align}4-x^2\quad \text{for}\quad |x| < 2\\x^2-4\quad \text{for}\quad |x| > 2\end{align}\right.$$

I suspect there are zeroes at 2 and -2 looking at the graph of the function. But how would find the zeroes.So that I can find the f interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $y=|4-x^2|$ is symmetric about the $y$-axis. So if we understand its behaviour for $x\ge 0$, we will know everything.

We have $|4-x^2|=4-x^2$ if $|x|\le 2$, and $|4-x^2|=x^2-4$ if $|x|\gt 2$.

It is I think clear that $4-x^2$ is decreasing in the interval $[0,2]$. It is also clear that $x^2-4$ is increasing in the interval $[2,\infty]$. Derivatives can be used to show these things, but they are not necessary.

So our function is decreasing in $[0,2]$ and increasing in $[2,\infty)$.

Now look at the reflection in the $y$-axis. We conclude that our function is decreasing in $(-\infty,-2]$ and increasing in $[-2,0]$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the derivative:

$$f'(x) = \left\{\begin{align}-2x \quad \text{for} \quad |x| < 2 \\2x \quad \text{for} \quad |x| >  2\end{align} \right\}$$

So $f$ is decreasing in the intervalls $(-\infty,-2]$ and $[0,2]$ and increasing in the intervalls $[-2,0]$ and $[2,\infty)$.

Comment: I know its correct but how do we know that zero is an interval in the function? If I did not have a graph because then all I would see are x=2,-2

Answer (score 1):

First things first, we need to know the derivative of f, it turns out this is it (remember that the absolute value of something is the same as taking the square root of something's square):
$f'(x)=-\frac{2x(4-x^2)}{\sqrt{(4-x^2)^2}}$

Now we need to determine critical points of the derivative (places that it is zero or that have a discontinuity).

Discontinuities arise when $x = 2$ and $x=-2$ from the bottom, so we know those are critical points.  It's trivial to confirm that those do in fact make a zero on the top, as does x = 0.  Thus our critical points are -2, 0, and 2.  This gives us the intervals $(-\infty,-2),(-2,0),(0,2),(2,\infty)$.  We must now check one point in each of these intervals to determine if the function is increasing or decreasing on the interval.  In this place I'd pick -3 for the first interval, -1 for the second, 1 for the third, and 3 for the last.

To check for increasing or decreasing we need only plug the chosen value into the derivative and determine if it is negative or positive.  If positive the function is increasing in that interval, if negative the function is decreasing in the interval.  Note that the bottom will always be positive for this function, so you can ignore the bottom for this step.

At this point it becomes clear that the function is decreasing on the first interval, increasing on the second, decreasing on the third, and increasing on the fourth.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Also, you are correct that there are zeros at -2 and 2.  This can be verified by plugging those values in for x and seeing that a zero is returned.